# How come this C program does not crash?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

This is from the book: [Understanding and Using C Pointers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344186)

> If memory is re‐ peatedly allocated and then lost, then the program
>   may terminate when more memory is needed but malloc cannot allocate it
>   because it ran out of memory. In extreme cases, the operating system
>   may crash. This is illustrated in the following simple example:

```
char *chunk; 
while (1) { 
    chunk = (char*) malloc(1000000); 
    printf("Allocating\n"); 
}
```

> The variable chunk is assigned memory from
>   the heap. However, this memory is not freed before another block of
>   memory is assigned to it. Eventually, the application will run out of
>   memory and terminate abnormally.

**So to my question:** 
I have this sample code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *chunk; 
    while (1) {
        chunk = (char*) malloc(100000000);
        printf("Allocating\n"); 
    }
}
```

Well I am expecting my system to run out of memory but the program keeps running and I see the text

```
Allocating...
```

all the time?

Comment: @EugeneSh. 100Mb? But it is in a for loop, I am constantly allocating new 100 Mbs ?

Comment: And besides, you don't do anything with this memory. So why should it crash? Even if it cannot allocate anything, `malloc()` returns `NULL` and the show goes on.

Comment: malloc() itself should not crash. It'll return NULL if it cannot allocate memory

Comment: Oh, sorry. Haven't noticed the loop.

Comment: @KorayTugay People are probably downvoting because you don't explain why you assume it should crash. Always explain what you think is going on and why.

Comment: RFTM sometimes enlights ...

Comment: @KorayTugay, no you are **not** "constantly allocating new 100 Mbs".  You are "constantly **trying to allocate** 100 Mbs".  That's not the same thing.

Comment: The manual to `malloc()` and in there especially the `RETURN VALUE` and `ERRORS` (if any) sections.

Comment: Please read carefully (emphasis be my): "*... the program **may** terminate ...*" and "***Eventually**, the application will [...] terminate abnormally.*"

Comment: That program doesn't finish abnormally.  That program doesn't finish.  **malloc(3)** will begin to return `NULL` when the virtual memory is exhausted and continue forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux I presume?

Just because you get back a pointer doesn't mean you actually reserved that memory. You have to physically touch the page for it to be yours.

Comment: So you are saying it will crash on first read/write? Unlikely. If not null of course..

Comment: I added this line in the loop, still not crashing: *chunk = 'c';

Comment: You only touched one *page*. You need to touch every page in that sequence, then wait for it to fill your RAM *and* your pagefile/swap. @Eugene, on the first read/write? No, I never said that.

Comment: @Blindy So what do you mean by "touch"?

Comment: @EugeneSh write to them. To *every* page. Simply zeroing out that memory will eventually (that's a lot of zeroes!) lead to a crash.

Comment: @Blindy Crash with what error? The memory is correctly allocated.So how can it be detected?

Comment: It's not allocated until you physically gain ownership of it. `malloc` is sort of a kind-of-promise, the materialization of the memory pointed to by what it returns only happens when you access it. Give it a try rather than arguing, or look it up online (or on this site), every beginner brings it up at some point or other.

Comment: If OP touches every page in the loop, malloc will return `NULL` eventually. But if OP allocates (but not touches) hundreds of GBs, then after touches them, weird things may occur. Kernel would try to map virtual addresses to physical addresses, and when it's no longer able to, it may either crash the process or try using a ramfs if possible.

Comment: I am not arguing, I am asking. It's looks weird to me that such a thing cannot be handled. I think @nos answered it.

Comment: Ah, Blindy already said a similar thing in another answer's comment section :)

Comment: For the record, I disagree with their design decision regarding this. I see no practical application where this would be a good thing. However for most things I write in Linux, whether it crashes on `malloc` or in the subsequent (but close) access to said memory it makes little difference.

Comment: @nos Isn't it `vm.overcommit_memory=2`? According to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Blindy Can you improve your answer a bit, summarising / including the comments?

Comment: How about calloc(100000000,sizeof(int)); ? Shouldn't this break?

Comment: How can one gain ownership of memory?  I went to the market to buy my laptop and got an invoice.  Malloc returns the memory already allocated and owned (in linux) (and zeroed, for security reasons) from the system.  No need to touch the memory, if you don't want to begin swapping.  When no more virtual mem is available, **malloc(3)** just returns `NULL`. What makes the program to crash normally is to try to access the memory from a `NULL` value returned **malloc(3)**, which makes to acces page 0 and get a `SIGSEGV` trap.

Comment: @LuisColorado, in your "witty" little anecdote you forget that you didn't buy your users' memory too. You have no right to it other that what they give you through their OS's memory manager. As to the rest, I'll reiterate, quit arguing, crack open a manual and seek enlightenment. Generally it's a better use of your time (also applies to life).

Answer (score 6):

When there isn't enough memory `malloc` probably returns NULL. Add a check for that.

```
while (1) {
    printf("Allocating\n"); 
    chunk = malloc(100000000);
    if ( chunk == NULL )
    {
       printf("Memory allocation not successful.\n");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Memory allocation successful.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's correct, Linux returns valid values if you never touch the pages it returns. It crashes when accessing pages that don't fit in (virtual) memory anymore. Not sure why this is getting upvoted, this is just not what happens in Linux.

Comment: I tried the code on cygwin. After a while, I got the "not successful" messages.

Comment: @RSahu, once more with more reading comprehension. Windows actually reserves the memory before returning it.

Comment: Well in all fairness, the OP hasn't mentioned what platform he runs on.

Comment: @Blindy, so does Linux, depending on the value of `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.

Comment: Please, don't use type casting in the return value from malloc.

Answer (score 1):

The program you run is not incorrect.  It doesn't have to terminate abnormally.  The reason of premature termination is that it consumes all memory in your computer, so if you don't take the correct measures, it will die.

Linux (and unix in general) imposes some limits to the processes running on a system.  In linux, all these limits (see **ulimit(2)** system call) are by default, fixed to `unlimited`.

When a process in linux tries to get more memory than the system has and allocates the remainder virtual memory, the kernel selects a process (the best candidate is the process trying to eat all memory) and kills it to recover some memory.  This is perhaps why the text you read says *it terminates abnormally*.  You note this because the system passes a while trying to swap in all the memory you are allocating and the swapper demands all the kernel attention (so your system seems to hang for a while ---it doesn't, just wait)

But you can do this kind of test:  Try to limit the virtual memory allocated to a process (with ulimit command, see **bash(1)**), so the system can cope with memory eating programs.  Use the command

```
$ ulimit -v 100000 # this allows for 100.000 kb of virtual memory
```

and rerun the program (It will be able to expand up to 100Mb and no more).  You'll see it doesn't stop.  It runs forever.  Once it has exhausted all the memory it can, **malloc(3)** begins to return `NULL` and the process never stop.  You'll see (via **ps(1)** command) that the program has allocated up to the limit you imposed and no more and it's running, consuming 100% of cpu time.  And everything is under control.  I tried the following variant of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char *chunk;
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (malloc(1000000)) i++; 
    printf("run for %i times.\n", i);
}
```

which counts the number of successful allocations before it runs out of memory and prints that number on `stdout`.  After fixing ulimit to 100Mb (`ulimit -v 1000000`) this program output:

```
$ pru
run for 97 times.
```

(you will see this is under 100Mb) So, voila!